# What is the best cryptographic hash function that generates 16-bit hashes values in openssl?

Tags: c, openssl, sha, sha256, cryptographic-hash-function

I was thinking of just using SHA256 and then using only the first two bytes of the result. Is there anything wrong with this approach?

NOTE: The concern here is not malicious attacks, but to ensure the best possible protection against random bit flips.

Comment: in general this sounds like a bad idea since the hash function is not designed to prevent collisions if you don't use its entire output.

Comment: @Gabriel so what is a better idea?

Comment: 16 bits can easily be brute-forced. Don't even bother trying for "cryptographic security" if you can't invest in a few bits more.

Comment: @KerrekSB I don't need perfect security, just something that is as secure as possible at 16 bits.

Comment: @Matt: If 16 bit is as secure as 100ms of computing time, do you really care if it's secure at all? Just make the hash function return constantly zero, and you have the same effective security...

Comment: @KerrekSB please read the note I added to my question.

Comment: If you want to protect against random bit flips, perhaps a crypto hash isn't right - a parity scheme or more advanced ECC checksum might be better.

Comment: @twalberg No, that would just be simpler, but not better.

Comment: @Matt  If you want to drive a nail into a wall you ought to use a hammer. Sure, you can drive the nail using a shoe, but why would you want to?

Comment: @NikBougalis So where can I find a hammer?

Comment: @Matt That depends how big your blocks are, how many errors you expect (i.e. how noisy your channel is) and how reliably you want to be able to detect them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any hash that satisfies the [strict avalanche criterion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avalanche_effect#Strict_avalanche_criterion) (that is, if any bit is flipped in the input, every bit in the output will be flipped with a probability of 50%) may be used in this way, and that includes every cryptographic hash in common use, including SHA512. There are security implications to using very short hashes, but if they really aren't relevant, as you claim, you're free to select the fastest hash available (probably MD5).

Since short hashes will be particularly vulnerable to the birthday paradox, though, consider using longer hashes anyway. If you're generating so many hashes that 16 bits versus 256 bits is significant, you *will* run into duplicates even without malicious attackers.

Comment: Can I take just the first 16 bits of an MD5 hash? Or is it a bad idea to use a subset of it?

Comment: There's nothing *inherently* insecure about doing that with a proper cryptographic hash, which MD5, despite its discovered weaknesses, is; but like I said, you almost certainly don't want to do that.

Comment: Your question is really not possible to answer. We don't know what your criteria are, and nobody that I know of has really studied the behavior of the "chopped" MD5 you plan to use and not in the way you plan to use it. The answer would depend on way too many factors. Why not use a proper error detection algorithm if that's your concern?

Comment: @NikBougalis, the strict avalanche criterion guarantees that chopping up a cryptographic hash like that is safe. But you're right that he should be using a proper error detection algorithm instead.

Comment: @Cairnarvon no it says nothing about the *safety* of this scheme. It says that if a single input bit is complemented every output bit has a 50% probability of flipping. While this may suggest that a chopped hash is fine for "random bit flip" errors, in reality it's not quite so clear cut how this helps in *error detection*. And does MD5 satisfy SAC to begin with?